# c++ How to print in a file a double decimal number with comma(instead of dot)

Tags: c++, printing, locale, fstream, cout

I need to print a csv file with numbers.
When the file is printed , I have numbers with dots, but I need them with commas.

Here an example.
If I print this number in terminal using locale method, I obtain a number with comma, but in the file I have the same number but with dot. I do not understand why.
How could I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>     // std::string, std::to_string
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double x = 2.87;
    std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE");
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    ofstream outputfile ("out.csv");
    if (outputfile.is_open())
        {
            outputfile  <<to_string(x)<<"\n\n";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: imbue the ofstream object, not cout.

Comment: @Neil [Doesn't seem to help](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2947e8488c8fb6a2).

Comment: Note that you need to include `<clocale>` for `std::setlocale`. It may work without the header, but there's no guarantee (for instance, it doesn't compile without it in Visual C++).

Comment: The file is csv, not cvs

Comment: I corrected , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locales are system-specific. You probably just made a typo; try `"de-DE"`, which will probably work (at least it does on my Windows).

---

However, if your program is not inherently German-centric, then abusing the German locale just for the side effect of getting a specific decimal point character is bad programming style, I think.

Here is an alternative solution using [`std::numpunct::do_decimal_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/decimal_point):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

struct Comma final : std::numpunct<char>
{
    char do_decimal_point() const override { return ','; }
};

int main()
{
    std::ofstream os("out.csv");
    os.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new Comma));
    double d = 2.87;
    os << d << '\n'; // prints 2,87 into the file
}
```

This code specifically states that it just wants the standard C++ formatting with only the decimal point character replaced with `','`. It makes no reference to specific countries or languages, or system-dependent properties.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `std::to_string()` uses the C locale libraries. It appears that `"de_DE"` is not a valid locale on your machine (or Coliru for that matter), leading to the default C locale being used and using `.`. The solution is to use `"de_DE.UTF-8"`. As an aside, using `""` for `std::locale` will not always produce commas; instead, it will depend on the locale set for your machine.

Comment: More precisely, `std::to_string` is defined to work in terms of `sprintf`, and `sprintf` uses the C locale libraries.